# Click Events Not Working on Nexus S ICS (4.0.4) in All Browsers

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm having a lot of trouble with my Nexus S, and I'm wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong.  Basically, click events via jQuery don't work with the Nexus S running Android ICS (Ice Cream Sandwich) 4.0.4 in all browsers.  I've tried the stock browser, Opera Mobile, and FireFox.

The same code will work with the Nexus S running Android 2.3 Gingerbread.  Also works fine on an iPhone 4 and Samsung Galaxy SII running Android 4.0.3.

Any advice?  Or is this perhaps a bug to report to Google?

Here's the basic code, also using modernizer, responsive, and obviously jQuery.
Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div>

    <p><a id="red" href="" target="_self">CHANGE TO RED</a></p>
    <p><a id="green" href="" target="_self">CHANGE TO GREEN</a></p>
    <p><a id="blue" href="" target="_self">CHANGE TO BLUE</a></p>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $("#red").click( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").css("background-color", "#CC0000");

    } );

    $("#green").click( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").css("background-color", "#00CC00");

    } );

    $("#blue").click( function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").css("background-color", "#0000CC");

    } );

} );
```

Comment: It appears the issue was with Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/).  I've been using the latest version, that being 2.5.3, but downloading it again from the HTML5 boilerplate seems to have solved the issue.  Since both variants I used a minified, I cannot easily spot the difference.

Comment: Hmm... well maybe, now things seem to be flaky.  Urgh!  More testing!

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue, and I traced it down to some of the div or p elements on my page containing more than 9 characters. As soon as I truncate the text of these elements it works again. Sounds crazy I know. I cannot even tell why it treats these elements differently, changing the CSS doesn't help, the only thing that works is moving the offending elements higher up in the tags structure... Maybe you can try truncating the text of your links if that's all the page contains.

Answer (score 0):

Put a # or javascript:void(0); in href attributes of those anchor tags

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make any difference.